# Blazor WASM: MudTextField and browser's autocomplete

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

MudTextField is used to enter the login (phone number with a mask).
If the browser autocompletes the saved login value in the field, it is not read when processing the input - the Value and the Text of the MudTextField remain empty.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a component bug?

```
<MudTextField Mask="@_mask1" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentText="@($"+{_dialCode}")" Margin="Margin.Dense" Style="height:36px" FullWidth="true" ref="_txt" T="string" 
@bind-Text="_phone" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Clearable="true" InputType="InputType.Telephone"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by using MudInput instead of MudTextField